# Religious symbol Om on an anklet

Tags: belief, women, om, symbols

I have seen few friends of mine wearing anklets with symbol Om on them these days! Heard somewhere that an Om pendant can't be worn with an anklet. Is that true? If yes, why?

Comment: Superstition. Swami Vivekananda - "...the Hindus have no sense of blasphemy; to speak of holy things in any way is to them in itself a sanctification." Om sanctifies everything.

Comment: Probably because these holy symbols are generally revered and kept near the head not the feet. The 'Om' symbol in an anklet would be constantly touching the feet which could be construed as an insult to it.